# JavaScript Code isn't working under XP

Tags: javascript, windows-xp

I am using this JS code for show and hide some div elements on my side - it is working perfectly on W7/W8 and all browsers, but for XP it doesn't work at all, am I something missing about JS libraries supported in XP or something?

Thanks for any replies in advance.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var divState = {};
    function showhide(id) {
        if (document.getElementById) {
            var divid = document.getElementById(id);
            divState[id] = (divState[id]) ? false : true;
            //close others
            for (var div in divState){
                if (divState[div] && div != id){
                    document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
                    divState[div] = false;
                }
            }
            divid.style.display = (divid.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Javascript isn't OS biased. It's likely the browser version on your XP machine has some issue - a browser plugin that's causing conflicts possibly.

Comment: It's unlikely to be related to the OS, but rather to the browser.  Open IE's console (F12) and look for errors, then edit your question to include whatever errors you find.

Comment: It has nothing to do with OS. Better take a look at how JS is implemented and works at paul irishs blog

Comment: Tried with all browsers on the machine - all browser result in the same problem, all div's are shown and toggle event doesn't work, strangely on W7 computers it works perfectly - but you are right maybe it is just an issue of the specific computer

Answer (score 0):

It can be because `'block'` is the default value of `display` for divs, i.e. if the actual `style.display` is `''`, then the div will act as a block. Try inverting your check like this:

```
divid.style.display = (divid.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I tried and sadly it doesn't work, I will crosscheck with other computers running XP

Comment: I agree with the other comments that it can't be something specific to Windows XP. Which browser(s) are you testing on?

Comment: I crosschecked with IE8&9, Chrome, FF and Safari on the computer w7 and XP. Yeah maybe it is just an issue with the one computer and I am looking for a problem which isn't caused by the code. I will crosscheck again and will reply if I found the issue